# PowerShell to replace string having double quotes

Tags: powershell

I have a file and I want to replace below line in file with blank string

```
 optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\sql2016;Initial Catalog=psdb;Integrated Security=SSPI");
```

below PowerShell code is doing nothing. please advise

```
(Get-Content $fileName2) -replace "^optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer.*$", "a" | Set-Content $fileName2
```

Comment: The string you want to replace has a leading space. Is that intentional?

Comment: oh!.. thanks man.. i changed to ^* and it worked..

Comment: Put that as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: i dont see accept button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you want to replace has a leading space. Is that intentional?
thanks @ansgar

i changed to ^* and it worked.